What should I do to prevent the enemy from falling off the platform?? Godot 4.3
I am have my enemy Slime in my game on Godot.
This is his code:
extends CharacterBody2D


const SPEED = 35
const SPEED_FOR_DETECTED = 45

var hp = 100
var player = null
var player_chese = false
var direction = Vector2.ZERO

@onready var TimerForMoving = $TimerForMoving
@onready var TimerForIdle = $TimerForIdle
@onready var anim = $AnimatedSprite2D

enum {
    IDLE,
    MOVING,
    DETECTED
}
var state = IDLE

var Axis = [Vector2.LEFT, Vector2.RIGHT]

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity += get_gravity() * delta

    if state == IDLE:
        if TimerForIdle.is_stopped():
            velocity = Vector2.ZERO
            TimerForIdle.start(randi_range(1, 4))
            
    elif state == MOVING:
        if TimerForMoving.is_stopped():
            TimerForMoving.start(randi_range(1, 4))
            velocity = Axis.pick_random() * SPEED
    
    elif state == DETECTED:
        TimerForIdle.stop()
        TimerForMoving.stop()
        var pos = (player.global_position - self.global_position).normalized()
        velocity = (Vector2.LEFT if Vector2.RIGHT.dot(pos) < Vector2.LEFT.dot(pos) else Vector2.RIGHT) * SPEED_FOR_DETECTED
    
    
    check_down(velocity)
    
    move_and_slide()
    

func check_down(veloc: Vector2):
    var moment_speed = SPEED if state == IDLE else SPEED_FOR_DETECTED
    veloc = veloc.normalized()
    if veloc == Vector2.LEFT and !$RayCast2DL.is_colliding():
        print("left ray")
        veloc = Vector2.RIGHT * moment_speed
    elif veloc == Vector2.RIGHT and !$RayCast2DR.is_colliding():
        print("Right ray")
        veloc == Vector2.LEFT * moment_speed


func _on_area_2d_entered_body_entered(body: Node2D) -> void:
    player = body
    player_chese = true
    state = DETECTED
    print("Enemy <Slime> detected Player;")


func _on_timer_for_moving_timeout() -> void:
    state = IDLE


func _on_timer_for_idle_timeout() -> void:
    state = MOVING


func _on_area_2d_exit_body_exited(body: Node2D) -> void:
    player = null
    player_chese = false
    state = IDLE
    print("Enemy <Slime> can not detected Player.")

I have problem with
check_downcheck_down()

In this function, I check if the raycasts have worked and if the enemy is heading towards the same raycast. But the recast is activated and nothing changes, the Slime falls!!! Here is a photo with raycasts and how it falls:
Falling
When it falls, the raycast stops burning and the desired print is written to the chat
Settings Raycasts
I've reviewed the guide on them, tried to rearrange and rewritten the code 3 times already, I don't understand why this is happening(

Raycasts are always a struggle! Your code looks solid, I don't think that's where your issue is.
Based on your second screenshot, it looks like the terrain is on the same collision layer as your raycast mask, which is good.
Is the box collision at the bottom half of the slime on that same collision layer? It looks like the raycasts intersect it, which would explain why the rays keep colliding even when they shouldn't be.

The problem is, that your function is setting its parameter. This will not alter the Vector you give to the function. So to make your code work it is as simple as changing two lines:
func check_down(veloc: Vector2):
var moment_speed = SPEED if state == IDLE else SPEED_FOR_DETECTED
veloc = veloc.normalized()
if veloc == Vector2.LEFT and !$RayCast2DL.is_colliding():
    print("left ray")
    velocity =  Vector2.RIGHT * moment_speed
elif veloc == Vector2.RIGHT and !$RayCast2DR.is_colliding():
    print("Right ray")
    velocity = Vector2.LEFT * moment_speed

Just set velocityinstead of veloc.
